# Packed/minified javascript failing in IE6 - how to debug?

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-6, minify

I have a number of files which I combine and pack to produce a single, minified JS file. The problem is that when I minify the file (using [packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/)), IE6 gives one of its characteristic helpful error messages.

```
Line: 12      // of course, line 12 is an empty line
Char: 1
Error: Expected ')'
Code: 0
```

The thing is: it works fine in IE7, Firefox and Chrome the problem only comes up for IE6.

Unpacked, I have almost 200kb of scripts spread through 8 files. How on earth do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have their way of doing it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2004/10/26/247912.aspx

http://www.jonathanboutelle.com/mt/archives/2006/01/howto_debug_jav.html

Answer (score 1):

Like CMS said, the [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) is a great tool to compress and obfuscate your code, try that.

I use the following code on my javascript files. I'm running on OSX, but the command should be identical on Linux and possibly also on Windows (though I never tried).

```
java -jar /path/to/yuicompressor-2.4.jar --charset utf8 -o ~/path/to/scriptname.min.js ~/path/to/scriptname.js
```

Where **~/path/to/** is the path to wherever your javascript file is, **scriptname.min.js** is the name of the minimized/obfuscated end result, and **scriptname.js** is the original file.

I'm assuming you cannot just 'forget' about IE6? One of my new year wishes is that the last 23% of IE6 users on the internet *finally* upgrade to a more decent/up-to-date browser :-).

Hope this helps!

-Dave

Answer (score 1):

this is a very common problem with ie6,
you have to pay attention to the closures in your code,

the condition statements must be with { - } ... and function too.

```
if(){
}

function(){
};
```

you must put ; on the end of each statement , if not , the lines will merge into something that the browser cannot understand.

i use [jslint.com](http://jslint.com) for javascript debugging.
look for the "missing semicolon" in the error list.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already verified that the un-minified code can run successfully in IE6?  If so, because this is a syntax error and not a runtime error, the next step I'd take is start halving the javascript, minifying it, and seeing when the problem stops being reported.  Then continue binary searching from there.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, I think the way I solved this problem in the end, and the way I generally tackle problems with minified code now, is to run it through [JSLint](http://jslint.com). Its extraordinary strictness will pick up problems (eg missing semicolons) that don't cause problems on non-minified code. You'll have to trudge through a lot of not-really-an-error messages, but the problem will be in there somewhere!